# Mejorar codificacion de consulta MySql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Tengo la siguiente una duda con respecto al código que implementé. Si bien es funcional, no me convence la forma en que logré dar solución al problema.

Lo que hace es calcular el promedio de los datos registrados a las horas exactas (ej: 08:00:00, 09:00:00) tomando **EL** registros de los 5 minutos previos, y **EL** de los 5 minutos posteriores. Ej: (05:55:00 + 06:00:00 + 06:05:00) / 3
y me devuelve algo como esto

```
| temp |        fecha
|______|____________________
| 21.1 | 2018-12-06 06:00:00
```

Debido a que **necesito los últimos 12 registros con el calculo anterior mencionado** lo logro realizando 3 consultas por los **minutos** específicos y las ultimas horas registradas ordenando por fecha y hora la consulta. Luego de obtener las 3 consultas individuales con limite de 12 y la primera con offset, en php proceso a tomar los registros obtenidos, hacer el calculo y entregar un array similar a esto:

```
| temp |        fecha
|______|____________________
| 21.1 | 2018-12-06 01:00:00
| 21.2 | 2018-12-06 02:00:00
| 21.3 | 2018-12-06 03:00:00
| 21.4 | 2018-12-06 04:00:00
| 21.5 | 2018-12-06 05:00:00
| 21.6 | 2018-12-06 06:00:00
| 21.7 | 2018-12-06 07:00:00
```

Si bien, esta solución me permite entregar los datos solicitados, **me gustaría saber** una forma de obtener todo en una sola consulta, incluyendo el calculo del promedio si es posible.

Este es el código que tengo en el modelo.

(lamentablemente cuando se modeló la base se dejo separada la fecha y hora :c )

como dato adicional después esto se va a un controlador que entrega la respuesta como json para cargarlo en un grafico de hightchart :)

```
$query1 = "SELECT temp,hora,fecha FROM estacion WHERE hora like '%:55:00' ORDER BY fecha DESC, hora DESC LIMIT 12 OFFSET 1"; 
$query2 = "SELECT temp,hora,fecha FROM estacion  WHERE hora like '%:00:00' ORDER BY fecha DESC, hora DESC LIMIT 12";
$query3 = "SELECT temp,hora,fecha FROM estacion  WHERE hora like '%:05:00' ORDER BY fecha DESC, hora DESC LIMIT 12"; 

$consulta1 = $this->db->query($query1);
$consulta1 = $consulta1->result_array();

$consulta2 = $this->db->query($query2);
$consulta2 = $consulta2 ->result_array() ;

$consulta3 = $this->db->query($query3);
$consulta3 = $consulta3 ->result_array() ;

foreach($consulta1 as $row => $index)
{
    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
    //calcula temperatura
    $informacion = (($index[$dato])+($consulta2[$row][$dato])+($consulta3[$row][$dato]))/3;
    $informacion = number_format($informacion, 2, '.', '');
    //arregla fecha y hora
    $fecha = $consulta2[$row]['fecha'] . " " . $consulta2[$row]['hora'];
    $fecha = strtotime($fecha) * 1000;

    $datos[$row][0] = $fecha;
    $datos[$row][1] = $informacion;
}

//print_r( $datos );
//$consulta->result_array();
return $datos;
```

Dejo el create table por si es necesario

```
CREATE TABLE `estacion` ( `fecha` date NOT NULL, `hora` time NOT NULL, `temp` float(3,1) DEFAULT NULL, `humedad` int(3) DEFAULT NULL, `pRocio` float(3,1) DEFAULT NULL, `vPromedio` float(3,1) DEFAULT NULL, `vRafaga` float(3,1) DEFAULT NULL, `direcViento` int(3) DEFAULT NULL, `precActual` float(5,1) DEFAULT NULL, `precHoy` float(5,1) DEFAULT NULL, `presion` float(7,2) DEFAULT NULL, `precTotal` float(7,2) DEFAULT NULL, `tempInterior` float(3,1) DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`fecha`,`hora`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

ejemplo datos

```
hora    | temp |   fecha
________|______|____________
03:55:00 | 21.1 | 2018-12-06
04:00:00 | 20.2 | 2018-12-06
04:05:00 | 24.2 | 2018-12-06
...
04:55:00 | 10.2 | 2018-12-06
05:00:00 | 12.2 | 2018-12-06
05:05:00 | 16.2 | 2018-12-06
...
05:55:00 | 22.2 | 2018-12-06
06:00:00 | 24.2 | 2018-12-06
06:05:00 | 26.2 | 2018-12-06
```

Comment: Puedes perfectamente unir las tres consultas en una sola y de paso traer la temperatura media en la misma consulta haciendo esto: `SELECT 
 AVG(temp) temp_promedio,
 hora,
 fecha 
FROM estacion 
WHERE 
 hora like '%:55:00' 
 OR hora like '%:00:00' 
 OR hora like '%:05:00' 
GROUP BY hora,fecha`. Luego no tienes que hacer todos los cálculos que haces luego, en la columna `temp_promedio` tendrás el promedio de los resultados obtenidos. Aunque dices que recibiste la tabla con fecha y hora separadas, si está a tu alcance normaliza tus tablas, te ahorrarás muchos dolores de cabeza.

Comment: Si bien es útil la respuesta, no entrega el resultado que busco, ya que agrupa por día
        {"temp_promedio":3.3,"hora":"00:00:00","fecha":"2014-07-23"},      {"temp_promedio":4.1,"hora":"00:00:00","fecha":"2014-07-24"}, {"temp_promedio":3.2,"hora":"00:00:00","fecha":"2014-07-25"}


Lo que yo busco que sea por ejemplo  (Temp de las 18:55:00 + Temp de las 19:00:00 + Temp de las 19:05:00) y así sucesivamente por hora

Answer (score 1, accepted):

luego de varios días dando vueltas al asunto, he logrado realizar la mayoría de operaciones en la consulta a la base de datos, esto incluyendo la transformación de la fecha con [UNIX_TIMESTAMP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp).

```
Select
      ROUND(((DATO00.temp + DATO05.temp + DATO55.temp) / 3), 2) as Promedio
    , UNIX_TIMESTAMP
        (
            CONVERT_TZ(ADDTIME(CONVERT(DATO00.fecha, DATETIME), DATO00.hora),'+00:00','-03:00')
        ) * 1000 as FechaUNIX
from 
(
    SELECT temp,hora,fecha,ADDTIME(CONVERT(fecha, DATETIME), hora) as fechaCompleta
    FROM estacion
    WHERE hora like '%:00:00'
    ORDER BY fecha DESC, hora DESC 
) DATO00
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT temp,hora,fecha,ADDTIME(CONVERT(fecha, DATETIME), hora) as fechaCompleta
    FROM estacion
    WHERE hora like '%:05:00'
    ORDER BY fecha DESC, hora DESC
) DATO05
//se agregan 5 minutos al datetime
ON AddTime(DATO00.fechaCompleta, '00:05:00') = DATO05.fechaCompleta
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT temp,hora,fecha,ADDTIME(CONVERT(fecha, DATETIME), hora) as fechaCompleta
    FROM estacion
    WHERE hora like '%:55:00'
    ORDER BY fecha DESC, hora DESC
) DATO55
//se agregan 10 minutos al datetime
ON DATE_SUB(DATO05.fechaCompleta, INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) = DATO55.fechaCompleta
ORDER BY DATO00.fechaCompleta DESC LIMIT 12
```

Si bien, la lógica de consultar en reiteradas ocasiones se mantiene, se pueden ejecutar simultáneamente mediante joins. De esta forma ademas, pude corroborar un grave error código anterior, ya que las consultas solo preguntaban por minutos exactos de manera diferenciada, y se dio un caso en donde no se encontraba uno de los registros, generando inconsistencia en los datos y por ende, se calculaba mal el promedio.

Por ejemplo

```
hora     | temp |   hora   | temp |   hora   | temp |  Prom | 
_________|______|__________|______|__________|______|_______| 
00:55:00 | 12.1 | 01:00:00 | 15.1 | 01:05:00 | 17.1 | 14.77 | 
01:55:00 | 18.2 | 02:00:00 | 25.1 | 03:05:00 | 15.1 | 19.46 | 
02:55:00 | 17.2 | 03:00:00 | 22.1 | 04:05:00 | 13.1 | 17.47 |
```

Como se puede apreciar, al no existir el registro de las `02:05:00`, procedía a calcular el promedio con el valor siguiente, que correspondía al registro de las `03:05:00` así como también había problemas al calcular el promedio de las `00:00:00` al no estar normalizada la fecha en la base de datos.

La consulta presentada actualmente, evita dichos problemas, ya que al no encontrar esos registros, no los lista gracias a los filtros de los inner join que toman la fechahora y le restan y suman minutos dependiendo de lo que necesito.

---

Para finalizar, adapté la consulta utilizando la clase [Query Builder](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#query-builder-class) en donde se utilizó el 2do metodo mencionado en la respuesta aceptada de [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16107730/convert-complex-join-query-in-codeigniter) para realizar los join de manera individual.

Luego se parametrizo la consulta con la informacion mencionada en esta [otra pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615792/does-codeigniter-automatically-prevent-sql-injection) en donde se menciona que existe una forma de prevenir injecion [Escaping Queries](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/queries.html#escaping-queries)

```
$estacion = 'estacion'; $dato = 'temp';

//Select de los %:00:00
$this->db   ->select($this->db->escape_str($dato).",hora,fecha,ADDTIME(CONVERT(fecha, DATETIME), hora) as fechaCompleta")
            ->from($this->db->escape_str($estacion))
            ->like('hora', ':00:00', 'before')
            ->order_by('fechaCompleta') ;

$Consulta00 = $this->db->_compile_select();
$this->db->_reset_select(); 

//Select de los %:05:00
$this->db   ->select($this->db->escape_str($dato).",hora,fecha,ADDTIME(CONVERT(fecha, DATETIME), hora) as fechaCompleta")
            ->from($this->db->escape_str($estacion))
            ->like('hora', ':05:00', 'before')
            ->order_by('fechaCompleta');

$Consulta05 = $this->db->_compile_select();
$this->db->_reset_select(); 

//Select de los %:55:00
$this->db   ->select($this->db->escape_str($dato).",hora,fecha,ADDTIME(CONVERT(fecha, DATETIME), hora) as fechaCompleta")
            ->from($this->db->escape_str($estacion))
            ->like('hora', ':55:00', 'before')
            ->order_by('fechaCompleta') ;

$Consulta55 = $this->db->_compile_select();
$this->db->_reset_select(); 

$query  = $this->db ->select("ROUND(((DATO00.".$this->db->escape_str($dato)." + DATO05.".$this->db->escape_str($dato)." + DATO55.".$this->db->escape_str($dato).") / 3), 2) as Promedio
                            , UNIX_TIMESTAMP
                                (
                                    CONVERT_TZ(DATO00.fechaCompleta,'+00:00','-03:00')
                                ) * 1000 as FechaUNIX"
                            )
                    ->from("($Consulta00) DATO00")
                    ->join("($Consulta05) DATO05","AddTime(DATO00.fechaCompleta, '00:05:00') = DATO05.fechaCompleta")
                    ->join("($Consulta55) DATO55","DATE_SUB(DATO05.fechaCompleta, INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) = DATO55.fechaCompleta")
                    ->order_by('DATO00.fechaCompleta DESC')
                    ->limit(12);

$query = $this->db->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

Como comentaba @acaedano, es mejor que normalices tus datos, ya sea en una tabla temporal (en memoria) o en una tabla a parte.

Pero otra sugerencia, un tanto engorrosa (por el formateo de fechas y hora) que puedes usar es esta.

Para ahorrarme el crear una tabla en alguna base de datos creare una consulta al vuelo de la forma hora, temp, fecha con la consulta de tipo.

```
SELECT '%:36:00' as hora, '20.1' as temp, DATE('2018/12/06') as fecha
UNION
SELECT '%:37:00' as hora, '20.2' as temp, DATE('2018/12/06') as fecha
...
```

Que será como una subtabla de la forma:

```
hora    | temp |   fecha
________|______|____________
%:36:00 | 20.1 | 2018-12-06
%:37:00 | 20.2 | 2018-12-06
```

Y le llamaré temp_table.

Luego, de esa subtabla, sacaré un objeto datetime hecho a partir de la fecha y hora concatenados y formateados.

```
STR_TO_DATE(-- _______________________________________
    CONCAT(                                        -- |
        DATE_FORMAT(a.fecha, '%Y/%m/%d'),          -- |
        'T',                                       -- |_    (Arregla los formatos de fecha y hora)
        replace(a.hora,'%:','') -- Se elimina '%:' -- |     Se crea fecha para filtrar por rango.
    ), -- Junta hora y fecha.                      -- |     Se podría arreglar esto con una tabla
    '%Y/%m/%dT%i:%s'                               -- |   + con datos timestamp.
) as fecha_completa, -- ______________________________|
```

Creando objetos datetime de la forma '%Y/%m/%dT%i:%s', un ejemplo sería así:

```
2018-12-06 00:36:00
```

Como no entendí bien lo que querías, dividiré en los dos puntos que logré entender de tu petición.

## Quieres hacer lo que hace tu código en PHP, literal.

Es decir, ingresando una hora (*h*), como centro, y sumando un intervalo de radio 5, i.e., [*h*-5,*h*+5] quieres sacar AVG(centro+extremos)

Entonces esta sería la consulta que almacenarías en una variable y a la que posteriormente le enlazarías la hora a consultar.

```
SELECT
    AVG(format_table.temp) as 'promedio'
FROM (
    SELECT
        STR_TO_DATE(
            CONCAT(
                DATE_FORMAT(temp_table.fecha, '%Y/%m/%d'),
                'T',
                replace(temp_table.hora, '%:', '')
            ),
            '%Y/%m/%dT%i:%s'
        ) as fecha_completa,
        temp
    FROM temp_table
) format_table
WHERE 
    -- Creas tu intervalo
    -- ___________________________________________________________________________________________________
    TIME(format_table.fecha_completa) = TIMESTAMP(
                                                DATE(fecha_completa), '00:45:00')
                    --                                                       |
                    --          Aqui 'bindeas' la fecha a consultar  ________|
    OR
    TIME(format_table.fecha_completa) = SUBDATE( -- La cota inferior
                                            TIMESTAMP(
                                                DATE(fecha_completa), '00:45:00'), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)
                    --                                                       |
                    --          Aqui 'bindeas' la fecha a consultar  ________|
    OR
    TIME(format_table.fecha_completa) = ADDDATE( -- La cota superior
                                            TIMESTAMP(
                                                DATE(fecha_completa), '00:45:00'), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)
                    --                                                       |
                    --          Aqui 'bindeas' la fecha a consultar  ________|
    -- ___________________________________________________________________________________________________
    -- Cierras tu intervalo
```

Para probar la consulta que hice, corre algo de este estilo.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_table AS -- Tabla temporal por flojera.
    SELECT '%:35:00' as hora, '20.1' as temp, DATE('2018/12/06') as fecha
    UNION
    SELECT '%:37:00' as hora, '20.2' as temp, DATE('2018/12/06') as fecha
    UNION
    SELECT '%:38:00' as hora, '20.3' as temp, DATE('2018/12/06') as fecha
    UNION
    SELECT '%:39:00' as hora, '20.4' as temp, DATE('2018/12/06') as fecha
    UNION
    SELECT '%:40:00' as hora, '25.4' as temp, DATE('2018/12/06') as fecha
    UNION
    SELECT '%:41:00' as hora, '20.5' as temp, DATE('2018/12/06') as fecha
    UNION
    SELECT '%:42:00' as hora, '20.6' as temp, DATE('2018/12/06') as fecha
    UNION
    SELECT '%:43:00' as hora, '20.7' as temp, DATE('2018/12/06') as fecha
    UNION
    SELECT '%:44:00' as hora, '20.8' as temp, DATE('2018/12/06') as fecha
    UNION
    SELECT '%:45:00' as hora, '20.9' as temp, DATE('2018/12/06') as fecha
    UNION
    SELECT '%:46:00' as hora, '20.1' as temp, DATE('2018/12/06') as fecha
    UNION
    SELECT '%:47:00' as hora, '20.1' as temp, DATE('2018/12/06') as fecha
    UNION
    SELECT '%:49:00' as hora, '20.1' as temp, DATE('2018/12/06') as fecha
    UNION
    SELECT '%:50:00' as hora, '20.1' as temp, DATE('2018/12/06') as fecha
    UNION
    SELECT '%:52:00' as hora, '20.1' as temp, DATE('2018/12/06') as fecha;

SELECT
    AVG(format_table.temp) as 'promedio'
FROM (
    SELECT
        STR_TO_DATE(
            CONCAT(
                DATE_FORMAT(temp_table.fecha, '%Y/%m/%d'),
                'T',
                replace(temp_table.hora, '%:', '')
            ),
            '%Y/%m/%dT%i:%s'
        ) as fecha_completa,
        temp
    FROM temp_table
) format_table
WHERE
    TIME(format_table.fecha_completa) = TIMESTAMP(
                                                DATE(fecha_completa), '00:45:00')
    OR
    TIME(format_table.fecha_completa) = SUBDATE(
                                            TIMESTAMP(
                                                DATE(fecha_completa), '00:45:00'), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)
    OR
    TIME(format_table.fecha_completa) = ADDDATE(
                                            TIMESTAMP(
                                                DATE(fecha_completa), '00:45:00'), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)
```

Resultando algo de este estilo:

```
|      promedio      |
| 22.133333333333336 |
```

Lo otro que entendí fue que quizás quisieras una nueva tabla de tipo.

```
|      hora      |     promedio de los tres puntos importantes del intervalo    |
```

Si es así, esta parte lleva todo el día matándome. Espero poder terminarlo pronto.

Comment: Estimado, actualice la pregunta, para ver si eso ayuda a comprender lo que hice :)